# Slick não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Possuo o seguinte código html

```html
   <html lang="pt-br">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/slick-theme.css" />
</head>

<body>
<!-- Cabeçalho da página -->
<div class="container">
    <header class="header-container">
        <hr class="container-hr">
        <img class="compasso-logo" src="./assets/logo-compasso.png" alt="logo compasso">
        <p class="header-primeiro-parag">
            < front end />
        </p>
        <p class="header-segundo-parag">
            developer challange
        </p>
    </header>
    <!-- Conteúdo principal -->
    <main class="container-main">
        <p class="main-titulo">produto</p>
        <hr>
        <h2 class="main-h2">conheça um pouco da nossa metodologia para criação de soluções inovadoras</h2>
        <p class="main-parag">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
            invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        </p>
        <img class="main-img" src="./assets/bg-section-1.svg" alt="developer">
    </main>
    <!-- Slider de cases -->
    <p class="cases">conheça alguns cases</p>
    <div class="carousel">
        <div><img class="prim-img" src="./assets/logo1.png" alt="drone">
        </div>
        <div><img class="seg-img" src="./assets/logo2.png" alt="keybord">
        </div>
        <div><img class="terc-img" src="./assets/logo3.png" alt="drone">
        </div>
        <div><img class="qua-img" src="./assets/logo4png" alt="keybord">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-cliente">
    <p class="cliente-area">área do cliente</p>
    <p class="cliente-acesso">acesse nossa plataforma exclusiva</p>
    <div class="container-form">
        <form action="" method="get" class="form-cliente">
            <div class="form-cliente-user">
                <label for="user">Usuário </label>
                <input type="text" name="user" id="user" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-cliente-senha">
                <label for="senha">Senha </label>
                <input type="senha" name="senha" id="senha" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-cliente-submit">
                <input type="submit" value="Acessar">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Footer da página -->
<footer class="footer">
    <img class="footer-img" src="./assets/logo.png" alt="logo compasso">
</footer>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

e o código slider

```js
$('.carousel').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToScroll: 4,
    arrows: true
});
```

porém o slider não funciona ná pagina. O que pode ser que está ocorrendo?

Comment: Está faltando a biblioteca do jquery na sua pergunta

Comment: @MarkVaaz ele deve ter colocado apenas o código da div que quer fazer o slide e o  javascript da mesma... Seria bom se ele podesse colocar o código completo para poder ajudar-lo

Comment: @AngeloSoares adicionei o código completo para melhor entendimento do mesmo

Comment: @PAOLASANTOS está exibindo algum erro no console do navegador?

Comment: @GutoXavier sim, "main.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function"

Comment: @PAOLASANTOS isso parece ser indício de que a biblioteca do **slick** não está acessível, troque `"./slick/slick.js"`  pelo caminho inteiro da biblioteca.

Comment: @GutoXavier mudei o caminho e outro erro no console apareceu net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3

Comment: CDN para o slick https://cdnjs.com/libraries/slick-carousel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz o download do [slick](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/archive/v1.8.1.zip) , extrai o conteúdo todo em uma pasta chamada **slick**, deixei todo o conteúdo na raiz da pasta. Segue o código:

```
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css" />
</head>

<body>
<!-- Cabeçalho da página -->
<div class="container">
    <header class="header-container">
        <hr class="container-hr">
        <img class="compasso-logo" src="./assets/logo-compasso.png" alt="logo compasso">
        <p class="header-primeiro-parag">
            < front end />
        </p>
        <p class="header-segundo-parag">
            developer challange
        </p>
    </header>
    <!-- Conteúdo principal -->
    <main class="container-main">
        <p class="main-titulo">produto</p>
        <hr>
        <h2 class="main-h2">conheça um pouco da nossa metodologia para criação de soluções inovadoras</h2>
        <p class="main-parag">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
            invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        </p>
        <img class="main-img" src="./assets/bg-section-1.svg" alt="developer">
    </main>
    <!-- Slider de cases -->
    <p class="cases">conheça alguns cases</p>
    <div class="carousel">
        <div><img class="prim-img" src="https://placeimg.com/1000/400/animals" alt="drone">
        </div>
        <div><img class="seg-img" src="https://placeimg.com/1000/400/arch" alt="keybord">
        </div>
        <div><img class="terc-img" src="https://placeimg.com/1000/400/nature" alt="drone">
        </div>
        <div><img class="qua-img" src="https://placeimg.com/1000/400/tech" alt="keybord">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-cliente">
    <p class="cliente-area">área do cliente</p>
    <p class="cliente-acesso">acesse nossa plataforma exclusiva</p>
    <div class="container-form">
        <form action="" method="get" class="form-cliente">
            <div class="form-cliente-user">
                <label for="user">Usuário </label>
                <input type="text" name="user" id="user" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-cliente-senha">
                <label for="senha">Senha </label>
                <input type="senha" name="senha" id="senha" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-cliente-submit">
                <input type="submit" value="Acessar">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Footer da página -->
<footer class="footer">
    <img class="footer-img" src="./assets/logo.png" alt="logo compasso">
</footer>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="slick/slick.js"></script>
<script>
$('.carousel').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToScroll: 4,
    arrows: true
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```